# Instantaneous velocity / average velocity question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> Answer true or false:
>
> If the average velocity of an object during the time interval from $t$ to
>   $t + ∆t$ is denoted as:
>   $$\frac{s(t + ∆t) - s(t)}{∆t}$$
>
> then the instantaneous velocity can be estimated by making $∆t$ as
>   close to zero as possible.

My answer: True.
[My reasoning.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdGfH.jpg)

Is this correct?

Comment: Thats actually (the) definition (of instantaneous change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the limit of  the average velocity $$\frac{s(t + ∆t) - s(t)}{∆t}$$

as ∆t approaches zero is exactly what is called instantaneous velocity.